# How Insert textbox value to Mysql in cPanel?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert textbox values to Mysql. i'm using cPanel server here. I have read some articles and I've come up to this code. but it's not inserting to the database. i'm sure about the connection has been established. what am i doing wrong here? any help? here the code please feel free to edit it.

```
if (!empty($name) || !empty($email) || !empty($office_id) || !empty($title) || !empty($story)) {


    $save_sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_story` (filename, name, email, office_id, title, story) VALUES ('$img_newname','$name','$email','$office_id','$title','$story')";

    $query = mysql_query($save_sql,$con) or die(mysql_error("Could not write information to the database")); 

    if (mysql_affected_rows($con) == 0) { 
                echo 'Your story was not created.'; 
            } else { 
                echo 'Your story was created successfully'; 
            } }
```

Comment: What error or problem you are getting?

Comment: that's my problem it doesn't return any error but when you check the database using SELECT * it says that the table is empty

Comment: may be this is not going into the if condition. check that is it going in the if condition or not. and check what it the values of $name, $email, $office_id etc.

Comment: thanks you. i will do that. i'll let you know what happened.

Comment: i tried to place this code after the declaration of variables that $POST the txtbox values. it doesn't echo anything . does it mean that the if statement is not read?

Answer (score 0):

Your all query parameters are not inserted in to DB table or only 'story' column not inserting?

You are sure about connection is established.
Following points might help you

1. If you are not getting error , have you tried to set error_reporting on , this might help you to get exact error.
2. Also try to echo $save_sql; this will some hint to you.
3. Try to check datatype you have defined for 'story'

Comment: Hi! thank you for answering. I haven't tried error_reporting. the datatype for "story" is varchar. how can i exactly do that? ok i will try to echo $save_sql. I have some codes after this which checks if the uploading of photos in the same form is successful.

Comment: is my syntax correct? though i know it doesnt have syntax error in my text editor, is it the best/ most effective syntax?

Comment: all of the parameters are not inserted. when i check the database it's empty

Comment: hi @Pragnesh Karia i tired echoing it but it doesn't display anything. what do you think is the problem here? thanks